# NodeJS+Bootstrapp+CSS : home buildup thumbnail gallery add white background to images

Tags: javascript, css, image-rendering

I have a container named mainContainer. In this container, I want to create a thumbnails gallery. 
Unfortunately, when I modify my CSS, I have some issues, I have some white background color instead of the background color for my mainContainer.

Here is the result page : [thumbnail gallery with unexpected white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ObH.jpg)
Here is the code of my page.

```
<html lang='fr'>
  <head>
    <% include includes/head-global %>
    <% include includes/head-bootstrap %>
  </head>
  <body onload="buildUpPage()">
    <div class = "container mainContainer" id = "mainContainer">
      <div class="row" id="galleryTargets">  <!-- Row : thumbnail          -->
      </div>
  </body>

  <% include tools/thumbnail %>
  <script>
  function buildUpPage() {
    var universData = <%- universData %>
    createThumbnail(universData.targets, "galleryTargets", "/" + univers.name + "/")
  }
  </script>
```

Express JS code for function createThumbnail :

```
<script>
  function addOneCaptionToContainer (item, containerDOM, baseImgTargetUrl) {
    var thumbnail = document.createElement("div")
    thumbnail.setAttribute("class", "thumbnail col-xs-4")

    var ref = document.createElement("a")
    ref.setAttribute("href", baseImgTargetUrl + item.name)
    ref.setAttribute("class", "thumbnail")
    thumbnail.appendChild(ref)

    var img =  document.createElement("img")
    img.setAttribute("src", "/"+item.backgroundImage)
    img.setAttribute("class", "imgThumbnails")
    ref.appendChild(img)

    document.getElementById(containerDOM).appendChild(thumbnail)
  }
  function createThumbnail(itemsList, containerDOM, baseImgTargetUrl) {
    for (let u of itemsList) {
      addOneCaptionToContainer(u, containerDOM, baseImgTargetUrl)
    }

  }
</script>
```

Now the CSS part :

```
.mainContainer{
 background-color: #A6A4AA;
 } 
.imgThumbnails {
 /*for the thumbnails in the gallery */
  margin: 0px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: #2C3756;  
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

I will appreciate an explanation. What must I do to remove these white background colors ?

---

The inheritance seems to cause problems : see [Properties not taken into account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3KUW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `padding` otherwise there will be empty space if you make the `background-color` transparent.

```
.thumbnail{
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Helo Hunzaboy and Chandra, thank you for your help. It helps me understanding what's going on. Unfortunately, I need more precision, the image still have a padding and a background-color.  I edited my post to give you the new result.

Comment: Hey @GuzimGlorantha

Comment: Hello @Hunzaboy, thank you for help. Any idea on how to override efficiently the two properties ?

Comment: @GuzimGlorantha , just add them at the bottom of your stylesheet.

Comment: I did, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks, @hunzaboy. The cache cleaning wasn't effective but the important tag was. It works fine, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap by default adds `background-color:white` to `thumbnail` class.

Override with Custom CSS

```
.thumbnail{
background-color:transparent;
}
```

and give a try.

Hope this helps..